# Eclipse CDT and asn1c (undefined reference to ...)

Tags: c++, c, linux, eclipse, asn.1

First of all: my english is poor, but I hope you understand me.
I develop under Linux (Debian) with Eclipse CDT (C++) and I need ASN.1 for my application. I installed asn1c (from http://lionet.info/) and attempted the example in the documentation, but it always fails.

I did the following:

I extracted and installed asn1c with follows commands in the terminal (as root):

```
tar xfz asn1c-0.9.27.tar.gz
cd asn1c-0.9.27
./configure
make
make install
```

After this, I could use asn1c in the terminal. Now I tried the example in the documentation (asn1c-usage.pdf). I created a file named rectangle.asn1 with the following contents:

```
RectangleModule1 DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN
   Rectangle ::= SEQUENCE {
   height INTEGER,
   width INTEGER
}
END
```

After this, I compiled it in the terminal with follow command:

```
asn1c rectangle.asn1
```

Ok, it works without a warning and I get many .c and .h files. Now I created a new c++ project in eclipse and add the path to the compiled asn1 files. Then I wrote the main.cpp file with the following code:

```
#include <Rectangle.h>

int main() 
{
    Rectangle_t *rect = NULL;
    asn_DEF_Rectangle.free_struct(&asn_DEF_Rectangle, rect, 0);

    /* more code   …some time */

    return 0;
}
```

However, I can’t compile this code. I always get an error like this: undefined reference to 'asn_DEF_Rectangle'

Eclipse output:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/ASN1.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/root/Dokumente -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/ASN1.d" -MT"src/ASN1.d" -o "src/ASN1.o" "../src/ASN1.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/ASN1.cpp

Building target: ASN1
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "ASN1"  ./src/ASN1.o   
makefile:45: recipe for target 'ASN1' failed
./src/ASN1.o: In function `main':
/media/sf_NTS_Daten/Workspace/ASN1/Debug/../src/ASN1.cpp:6: undefined reference to `asn_DEF_Rectangle'
/media/sf_NTS_Daten/Workspace/ASN1/Debug/../src/ASN1.cpp:6: undefined reference to `asn_DEF_Rectangle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ASN1] Error 1
```

All examples I found (documentation and lionet.info) ends with an error (undefined reference to 'asn_DEF_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'). I don’t know the reason. The structures are working and I can fill it with values, but asn_DEF_Rectangle (in this case) generate an error. I have no idea what I can do. Did I need a library? ...I think the Linker need something...

Have someone tips or ideas? please...
I do not know how to continue…. :(

...by the way: I use the gcc compiler (eclipse cdt standard)

regards,
SBond

=============================================

## Edit 1:

ok....
to avoid any problems with Eclipse, I try another way:

-> I open this website: http://lionet.info/asn1c/asn1c.cgi (online asn1 generator)

-> Then I feed it with my example ASN.1 module:

```
RectangleModule1 DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN
   Rectangle ::= SEQUENCE {
   height INTEGER,
   width INTEGER
}
END
```

-> I press the "Proceed with ASN.1 compilation" button and download the compressed file "Fetch compiled C sources (71 Kb .tgz)"

-> I extract all files in a seperate folder: /root/ASN1_test

-> I create a main.cpp (in /root/ASN1_test) with following code:

```
#include <Rectangle.h>

int main() 
{
    Rectangle_t *rect = NULL;
    asn_DEF_Rectangle.free_struct(&asn_DEF_Rectangle, rect, 0);

    /* more code   …some time */

    return 0;
}
```

-> Now I want compile it with g++ and try this:

```
g++ -I/root/ASN1_test -o MyProgram main.cpp
```

but...

```
/tmp/ccwF42ix.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `asn_DEF_Rectangle'
main.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `asn_DEF_Rectangle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
root@debian:~/ASN1_test#
```

---

What did I wrong? How I can compile this code? :(

Comment: The linker command `g++  -o "ASN1"  ./src/ASN1.o` means that the auto-generated `c` files were not added to the project. I don't know Eclipse, but apparently just adding path is not enough.

Comment: ...I get the same error withouteclipse :(   (see Edit 1)

Comment: Show the non-eclipse command line. Does it list all the `.c` files generated by asn1?

Comment: yes. All files are in the same folder

Comment: Problem solved :D  All .c files must be inside of the workspace. ...a path outside of the workspace, produced errors.